# Installing Sql Server 2008 on Windows 7 RTM

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7

Has anybody found a way to install Sql Server 2008 on Windows 7 RTM?

The Windows 7 installer compatibility wizard indicated that 2008 has incompatibilities and the Sql Server 2008 installer causes the Windows 7 to throw up a warning and then eventually errors out with an "Object reference" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes its only an unfreindly error- just do it then get the SP1 before you do anything.

I did this on my dev machine and all is well.

PS make sure the machine is connected to the internet or you have all on the CD...

[SP1 download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en)

See this guidence too.
http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/05/14/installing-sql-server-express-on-windows-7-release-candidate.aspx

Creating a slipstream install so the install can get the SP1

http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/02/25/sql-server-2008-creating-a-merged-slisptream-drop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for u. I think it is better.
http://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-on-windows-7/